# MySQL LIKE performance with increased wildcards

Tags: mysql

I needed to find an embedded string in one of the columns and do some classification based on that.

To do so, I used `LIKE` statement like this :

```
select * from table where column like "%_ABC_%"   (did not intend to use _ as a wildcard)
```

But this was extremely slow. Later when I found that `_` is also a wildcard in MySQL, I removed it and the query ran way faster. Just curious to know if there is any explanation for this?

Comment: try to use mysql function LOCATE - https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-locate-function.php

Comment: you can add `EXPLAIN` before your query to understand the reason

Comment: Using `%_ABC_%` likely causes a lot of backtracking when searching for matches. I'd expect that instead searching for `_%ABC_%` probably behaves better (but maybe not).

Comment: Here is some fantastic reading for you on this https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning

Answer (score 1):

The underscore (`_`) wildcard character represents a single character, while the percent sign (`%`) represents a sequence of 0 to N characters. Your RDBMS is usually able to take profit of this and searches using the underscore wildcard perform faster.

Answer (score 0):

Percent sign `%` represents `0` to `N` characters, while underscore `_` represents a single character. It implies that the set of strings matching `%_ABC_%` is a subset of the set a strings matching `%ABC%`. MySQL engine can take benefit from it.